# Getting the best-fit parameters to create a new function

Tags: deep-learning

I am tyring to import the libraries below

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
```

**but it is returning below error, kindly help.**

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in 
     57 
---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     59

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in 
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     23             try:
---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
     25             finally:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
    241         else:
--> 242             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    243     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    341             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 342         return _load(spec)
    343

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      1 #import libraries
----> 2 from keras.models import Sequential
      3 from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
      4 
      5 #Build the LSTM network model

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras__init__.py in 
      1 from **future** import absolute_import
      2 
----> 3 from . import utils
      4 from . import activations
      5 from . import applications

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils__init__.py in 
      4 from . import data_utils
      5 from . import io_utils
----> 6 from . import conv_utils
      7 from . import losses_utils
      8 from . import metrics_utils

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py in 
      7 from six.moves import range
      8 import numpy as np
----> 9 from .. import backend as K
     10 
     11

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend__init__.py in 
----> 1 from .load_backend import epsilon
      2 from .load_backend import set_epsilon
      3 from .load_backend import floatx
      4 from .load_backend import set_floatx
      5 from .load_backend import cast_to_floatx

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\load_backend.py in 
     88 elif _BACKEND == 'tensorflow':
     89     sys.stderr.write('Using TensorFlow backend.\n')
---> 90     from .tensorflow_backend import *
     91 else:
     92     # Try and load external backend.

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py in 
      3 from **future** import print_function
      4 
----> 5 import tensorflow as tf
      6 from tensorflow.python.eager import context
      7 from tensorflow.python.framework import device as tfdev

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py in 
     39 import sys as _sys
     40 
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     43

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py in 
     48 import numpy as np
     49 
---> 50 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     51 
     52 # Protocol buffers

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in 
     67 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     68 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 69   raise ImportError(msg)
     70 
     71 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\NGROLAD\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\NGROLAD\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\NGROLAD\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\NGROLAD\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\NGROLAD\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

Comment: Get your indentation correct. The code is unreadable

Comment: I have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

Your question title does not match with the question but for the error you have got, this might help

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
```